How to dynamically change language in a Plasmo + React browser extension, independent of browser language?
I'm developing a browser extension using Plasmo and React, and I'm facing an issue with internationalization (i18n). Currently, the extension only uses the browser's language setting, but I want to allow users to change the language within the extension, regardless of the browser's language.
For example, if the browser language is set to English, the extension initially loads in English. However, I want to provide an option for users to switch to any other language that my extension supports (e.g., Vietnamese, Chinese, French) while using the extension, without changing the browser's language setting.
I've searched through various documentation, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve this. I noticed that chrome.i18n doesn't seem to have an API for changing the language dynamically.

I've implemented basic i18n using Plasmo recommended approach, which works fine for the initial load based on the browser's language.

I tried looking into chrome.i18n API, hoping to find a method to change the language programmatically, but couldn't find anything suitable.

I considered using a React i18n library like react-i18next, but I'm unsure how to integrate it properly with Plasmo and make it work in a browser extension context.

I expected to find a way to call a function or update a state that would trigger a language change throughout the extension, something like:
function changeLanguage(newLang) {
  // Some code to change the language
  // and update all translated strings in the UI
}


I also thought about storing the user's language preference in extension storage and applying it on load, but I'm not sure how to implement this effectively with Plasmo and React.


I'm looking for a solution that allows me to change the language dynamically within the extension, updates all translated strings immediately, and persists the user's language choice across extension restarts.
